# How to determine when to use Normal Approximation of binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

Currently I am studying probability for

Binomial Distribution

Normal Distribution

and Normal Approximation of binomial distribution

From my understanding is it correct that we use Normal approximation of binomial distribution when a problem asks for group of people or # of pairs of people

and we use Binomial Distribution is just when individual people

Is this correct? Thank you so much :)

Comment: Thumb rule is that the approximation is "good" if $np(1-p)\ge 9$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i've been taught, the aproximation is valid when:
\begin{equation*}
X \sim B(n,p) \Rightarrow X \sim N(np,np(1-p)) \text{ (aproximated) iff}\hspace{.2cm} n\geq 20, np > 5 \text{ and } n(1-p)>5
\end{equation*}
Hope it helped.

Comment: This is also what I've been taught. However, it seems there may sometimes be vagueness to the definitions of what it should be greater than. For example, I take it to be $np\textbf{≥}5$